# Seeding and Saving array in EF CF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two models in my ASP.NET MVC project.  When seeding to include test data I do the following:

```
context.Dialogs.Add(new Dialog
{
    Id = 1,
    Chapter = 1,
    Index = 0,
    DialogColor = "default-color",
    DialogText = "blah blah!",
    Character = "none",
    Transition = false,
    Fade = true,
    Timer = 0,
    Actions = new List<Action>
    {
        new Action { ActionText = "--continue--", ActionLink = 1, Id=1 }
    }
});
```

This saves the record in the Dialog table but the Actions are not saved, I know I can probably save the dialog first and then append an Action to it but I want to be able to add it all inline like above?

Dialog model:

```
public class Dialog
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Chapter { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string DialogColor { get; set; }
    public string DialogText { get; set; }
    public string Character { get; set; }
    public bool Transition { get; set; }
    public bool Fade { get; set; }
    public int Timer { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Action> Actions { get; set; }
}
```

Action Model:

```
public class Action
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ActionText { get; set; }
    public int ActionLink { get; set; }

    public Dialog Dialog { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Try this: **Don't** set the `Id` for any of the entities you add when seeding.

Comment: You probably no need to set id manually. It should be assigned by EF\SQL automatically in most of the cases (if you not using some specific id generated logic)

Comment: I did, tested before putting the ids in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your model to use an ICollection so entity framework will make the proper associations.  From this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/47296641-0426-49c2-b048-bf890c6d6af2/):

> The Entity Framework doesn't support collection properties that are
>   exposed as IEnumerable with Add and Remove methods.

In your dialog class update your property to:

```
 public virtual ICollection<Action> Actions { get; set; }
```

**EDIT:**

Couple other things to look for, are the navigation properties mapped?

You could try adding a fluent mapping:

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
  {
     modelBuilder.Entity<Dialog>()
        .HasMany(d => d.Actions)
        .WithOptional(a => a.Dialog);

  }
```

Is the FK actually getting mapped in the database?  Note: The Dialog_Id on the Actions table. If you don't have this, then EF isn't actually mapping your relationship

[image]

If none of this work, you could always explicitly add the entity to your context when creating it in the list:

```
     context.Dialogs.Add( new Dialog
     {
        Id = 1,
        Chapter = 1,
        Index = 0,
        DialogColor = "default-color",
        DialogText = "blah blah!",
        Character = "none",
        Transition = false,
        Fade = true,
        Timer = 0,
        Actions = new List<Action>
            {
                context.Actions.Add(new Action()
                                       {
                                          ActionText = "--continue--",
                                          ActionLink = 1, Id=1 
                                       })
            }
     } );
```

The [DbSet.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.add%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method will return the entity once it's been added to the context.

Comment: Nope still doesn't seem to save it, I can only think the save method is wrong

Comment: Expanded my answer, adding other solutions